# How to get whole style attribute at once in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div in my html. On a button click event, I want to get all style attribute at once, so that I can use it for another task

```
    <div id=popUp style="display: block; z-index: 1050; top: 371px; left: 847.75px;">
        </div>
    <button id="btn" value="submit">

$('#btn').on('click', function (event){
           var styleAttribute=$('#popUp').css('style');
console.log('styleAttribute',styleAttribute);
        });
```

It gives undefined. What I want is this as console.

```
display: block; z-index: 1050; top: 371px; left: 847.75px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**jQuery#attr**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to the attribute `style` instead of the [**jQuery#css**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) - which returns the properties of the `style`.

For individual style properties you can use [**jQuery#css**](http://api.jquery.com/css/), passing the property name, for example `.css('display')` and get the value of the `display` property.

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
   var styleAttribute = $('#popUp').attr('style');
   console.log('styleAttribute ', styleAttribute);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popUp" style="display: block; z-index: 1050; top: 371px; left: 847.75px">
</div>
<button id="btn" value="submit">Get style</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call with `attr()`

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
var styleAttribute=$('#popUp').attr('style');
console.log('styleAttribute',styleAttribute);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=popUp style="display: block; z-index: 1050; top: 371px; left: 847.75px;">
        </div>
    <button id="btn" value="submit">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use attr.

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  var styleAttribute = $('#popUp').attr('style');
  console.log(styleAttribute);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=popUp style="display: block; z-index: 1050; top: 371px; left: 847.75px;">
</div>
<button id="btn" value="submit">
```